# PHP Laravel - Unknown column in field list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

Ok, so I had the table "Users" which had a certain field list but then the table columns have been changed by the members of our team. The seeders and all other files are correct since I've had 2 other members test on their machines that everything works. For some reason, when trying to

`php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

it gives me that error, that I'm trying to put values into the Users table and it has to be with a certain field list when it is completely different now.

To be more specific, imagine that the Users table had a name and a password. Now it has an email, name, identification_number, birth_date.

It is still seen as having only the name and the password fields.

Going to the phpMyAdmin page, I can clearly see that the table has been updated with the new columns.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: sounds like your models are referring to other models. Eloquent is very smart about relationships.

Comment: Check the fillable property on your User Model.. you need to add email, name, identification_number, birth_date columns to that array.

Comment: Check `dropColumn` statements in your migrations.

Comment: Ok, so, from what I've gathered, there is a create_users_table_example and a create_users_table migration file. The first one is the one that has name email etc., but in the DatabaseSeeder.php file, it is not referenced at all, not even in the app/User.php file.